# Format datetime column into DD MONTH YYYY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi it maybe a very simple question but I am failing to format my `datetime` column in the format of `"16 October 2013"` any help/suggestions please !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [DD Month YYYY]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is convert function.  Look at MSDN [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function with format style 106. It gives you abbreviation for the month though.

```
  Select Convert(varChar(20), getdate(), 106)
```

If you need the full name of the month, you will need to buld your own with datename() function.

```
 Declare @dt datetime = getdate()
 Select str(day(@dt),2,0) + ' ' + DateName(month, @dt)  + ' ' + Str(Year(@dt), 4,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this one.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DD,GETUTCDATE())) +' '+ DATENAME(MM,GETUTCDATE())+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YY,GETUTCDATE()))
```