# Retrieving date from SQL Server in DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am battling with date retrieval from SQL Server. Can anyone help me? I want to run a query that will return a date in the format of `DD-Month-YYYY`. I tried several google searches and haven't got any help yet.

Here's how I do it:

```
SELECT OrderDate 
FROM tblOrders;
```

It returns `2010-01-23 00:00:00.000`. I want to retrieve: `23-January-2010`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689962/sql-server-format-date-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss/6689992#6689992

Comment: always try to leave the formatting of dates to be the responsibility of the presentation tier unless there is a real need to do this at query level (which there shouldnt be).

Answer (score 1):

A date is a date is a date. It would smell as sweet by any other name.

What you're asking about is formatting.

You can convert a date to a string using `convert`

```
 select convert(varchar(20), OrderDate,106) from orders
```

If you want to get the full month name, then you can use `datename`

```
 select datename(day, orderdate)+'-'
      + datename(month, orderdate)+'-'
      + datename(year,orderdate)
 from orders
```

Answer (score 1):

If its sql server 2012 you can choose FORMAT() function which provides easy formatting in comparison to predeccesor versions.

`SELECT FORMAT(Orderdate,'D','en-gb') as Formatted_Orderdate from tblOrders`

Refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(DAY(SYSDATETIME()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + DATENAME(MM, SYSDATETIME()) + '-' + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) AS VARCHAR(4)), 2) AS [DD Month YY]
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Answer (score 0):

I answered the same question a few days back

```
SELECT CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [DD Month YYYY
```

[Format datetime column into DD MONTH YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393362/format-datetime-column-into-dd-month-yyyy/19393405#19393405)